How to run a query with Spring Neo4jClient to Neo4jDB at the start of Spring Application automatically
I have a use case where I need to check if indexes and constraints are present in a neo4j database and add them if not present. This must be done when the spring application starts and cannot be done through an API call as I won't have access to the API on the server.
I've tried making use of @PostConstruct annotation, CommandLineRunner, ApplicationRunner and ApplicationListener to try and execute the query as soon as the Spring Boot application starts. But every time I'm getting the following error during Build stage of the AWS CodePipeline:
2024-11-18T18:50:12.160+0000 ERROR Application run failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Could not perform discovery for database 'neo4j'. No routing server available.; Error code 'N/A'

Suppressed: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.DiscoveryException: Failed to update routing table with server 'XXX.XX.0.XX:7687'.

If I remove the code trying to insert the indexes at startup, then no error is encountered, and the application is successfully deployed with the db calls through API calls working fine.
This the neo4jClient configuration I'm using:
@Configuration
public class Neo4jClientConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Neo4jClientConfig.class);

    @Value("${neo4j.uri}")
    private String dbURI;

    @Value("${neo4j.authentication.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${neo4j.authentication.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${neo4j.database}")
    private String dbName;

    @Bean
    public Neo4jClient neo4jClient () {
        Driver driver = GraphDatabase
                .driver(dbURI, AuthTokens.basic(username, password));
        return Neo4jClient.create(driver);
    }

}

I have also tried changing the protocols between bolt and neo4j but both of them don't work.
Is there some way to automatically call a method that would in turn insert indexes and constraints into the database whenever the spring application starts up?

obviously this can't work in the build stage. the question is, why is it booting the application in the build stage. if this is intentional, you should add a check (e.g. using ENVs) to skip the index initialising in the pipeline

I think that the best option to do this is to introduce neo4j-migrations (https://github.com/michael-simons/neo4j-migrations/) to your project.
It does exactly what you ask for (and even more).
Basically it is a good idea to have some kind of migration tool within your application (like flyway or liquibase for relational databases) to not come to a state where you need to manually invoke Cypher statements to migrate your data.
For the last bit in your question regarding the scheme: Please be aware that a connection via the bolt scheme always connects directly to an instance if Neo4j whereas the neo4j scheme will create a routing driver instance that e.g. sends read-only transactions to the followers in the cluster, etc.
